# What does もんね mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles, particle-mono

Consider the following sentence.

> お金持{かねも}ちになるもんね。

What does the 「もんね」 mean?

Without もんね、i.e.　「お金持ちになる。」, it means "becomes rich"。

Answer (score 16, accepted):

「～～もんね」 is a sentence-ender that is used mostly, if not exclusively, by children.  Technically, both 「もの/もん」 and 「ね」 are sentence-ending particles, so the two are combined in 「もんね」.

It is used to state or declare something boastfully, braggingly, etc. often with a hint of playfulness.

> "I'm gonna be rich; That's for sure!"
>
> "I'm gonna be rich, I promise!"

As an adult, you could use 「もんね」 ***kiddingly*** once in a while, but if you used it in a serious tone or used it too often, you would end up sounding pretty weird.  You might end up sounding like a manga/anime character if you used it repeatedly.

Comment: You can use it mockingly for someone else, right? (at least as もんな that works in my head) - 'yeah, since he's gonna be rich like he says (like that'll happen)'