# How do you use "ああして" and "もんね"

Tags: particles, phrases

[context are from here, it's a comic sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssHr.png)

> 相棒を**ああして**亡くしたショックで退職した**もんね**…かわいそうに

I would like to ask

1. The meaning of ああして
2. Can we tell the subject/the one who killed 相棒 from "相棒をああして亡くした"?
3. The meaning of もんね

I could figure 1. 2. despite my effort of searching, but in the case of 3. I doubt もんね is equivalent to ものね, since one of the entry in my dictionary says,

> もの：(｢ものね｣｢ものな｣などの形で)理由を表す。｢ね｣｢な｣などによって、軽い詠嘆の意が加わる。例、｢よくおわかりでしょう。前に行ったことがあります**ものね**｣

I noticed that ものね is succsessive to the reason in the dictionary example. (前に行ったことがある is the reason and よくわかります is the result/conclusion.) Apply this logic to the sentence in my question, we can conclude that 相棒を亡くしたショック is the reason, and that the result should be "彼は退職前より随分元気がない", cannot we？

It is also much appreciated if someone provide how they use "ああして" and "もんね".

Thank you for any help you provide.

Comment: Related　（ああ）: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58311/what-do-the-%e3%81%82%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b-and-%e6%b0%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-mean/58329#58329

Comment: Related （もんね）: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32322/what-does-%e3%82%82%e3%82%93%e3%81%ad-mean/32323#32323

Answer (score 2):

ああして is part of one of Japanese's many sets of four question words, in this case:

> こうして "in this way" "like this"
>   そうして "in that way" "like that" (nearby)
>   ああして "in that way" "like that" (distant)
>   どうして "in what way" "how"

Note that this どうして is different in meaning from the more common どうして meaning "why", though I think that usage originally derives from this one. The other three ～して forms do not have the same ambiguity. These forms are also largely equivalent in meaning to the ～やって forms こうやって, そうやって, ああやって and どうやって, which you might encounter a little more commonly.

At any rate, the meaning here is quite straightforward - 相棒を**ああして**亡くしたショック means "the shock of losing his partner **like that**". So it is referring to the way in which his partner died (which was presumably particularly gruesome or shocking, though this sentence doesn't tell us anything about the details, other than that the person this speaker is talking to is expected to know them).

The もんね, meanwhile, is indeed a more casual equivalent of the ものね that you listed in the question, and indicates that 相棒をああして亡くしたショックで退職した (the fact that he left his job due to the shock of losing his partner like that) is a reason or explanation for why 退職前よりずいぶん元気がない (he seems in a worse state/more depressed than he was before he left his job). This seems to follow quite logically. ものね or もんね can often be translated as "after all", which seems to fit well here.

I would translate the whole sentence along the lines of

> 相棒をああして亡くしたショックで退職したもんね…かわいそうに
>   He left his job due to the shock of losing his partner like that, after all... Poor guy.